# Why does jCaroussel Lite cut off text in some slides?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jQuery plugin called [jCarousel Lite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) to create a vertical scrolling Twitter ticker. Everything works fine, except for the fact that some tweets aren't shown completely. They're cut off before the last line of text. I can't seem to figure out what is causing the problem and it seems to occur more or less randomly too.

The page at http://www.reekx.nl/ shows the Twitter ticker in action (bottom right, titled 'Reekx op Twitter').

Is anybody able to tell me what's going wrong here and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The Carousel sets a height for the elements, and at the same time you have overflow:hidden in your CSS.

This bascily means you are telling the DIV that it should be 104px heigh, and all overflowing content should be hidden.

Ill try to find if you can disable a fixed height in carousel mean while :)

Could you try playing with the "**fit**" option?

---

You can try playing with the options, which can be found here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

But the 2 which is relevant should be:

```
$('#stwitterThing').cycle({ 
    fit:      1, 
    height:  auto
});
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it Marco. overflow:hidden is done by the plugin as well. So basically the problem is that the plugin calculates the height for the slides incorrectly and then covers up for this problem by hiding the overflow, correct?

Edit: I don't know what you mean by the 'fit' option by the way.

Comment: You're referring to a different plugin I'm afraid. I'm using jCarousel Lite (refer to the link in the original post). I'll look into this one though.